# What are the differences between the ELCA and UCC?

Tags: lutheranism, comparative-christianity

Looking for a church community for me and my child, young adult college age. So far trying to decide between ELCA (Evangelical Lutheran Church in America) and UCC (United Church of Christ). What are the differences between these two communities?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Have you considered the LCMS? They are quite a bit more orthodox than the ELCA

Comment: Personally, I’m not a Lutheran. But from a good number that I’ve talked to, the ELCA is a poor choice as it’s been corrupted by theological liberalism and is pretty irreverent. If you want a better church I’d go closer to something like LCMS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a text book answer. I can say I am a member of a small church here on the ND/MN border where it is a combination of ELCA and UCC. We are not formally/legally one entity but we act as one with one unified Church Council and a retired Presbyterian minister. All I know is it works wonderfully, because we want it to. It is this works or both congregations would cease to exist. The biggest difference is Lutherans tend to be what is called "high church" and UCC is "low church." What that means is Lutherans, including the ELCA, have more liturgical structure, more ritual than the UCC. For us we just compromised so the ELCA in our church is getting "lowered churched" and the UCC is experiencing a "higher church." And our Presbyterian minister reworked communion so both camps are happy. As a UCC I would not be able to handle the true high church of eh ELCA but our arrangement works. If you have kids ask about the Sunday School and what sources they use. So far our UCC and ELCA parents are happy. A great think about the ELCA and the UCC is they both have progressive stances on gay issues and marriage. The UCC was the first church to hire an openly gay minister in 1972 and our formal language was worked out about 1985. We use the phrase "open and affirming." The Lutherans had a harder, much harder time getting there so I would say about 4 years or so ago they too went progressive (this is the ELCA) and use the language "Reconciled in Christ." So on that critical social issue the UCC and ELCA are very compatible. The UCC has a reputation for being very strong on social and economic justice. Many ELCA are in line with that. I am UCC and will always be UCC but I love my ELCA church members.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Check out our [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how we do things around here. This answer could be improved by citing external links, such as resources produced by ELCA and UCC. Generally, external evidence is preferred to anecdotal evidence. Thank you for answering, and I hope you will stick around!